# The difference between noun clause and relative clause

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct? and Why?
Do these sentences mean the same thing?

> Julia helped me with the project yesterday, which saved my life.
> (relative clause)

> That Julia helped me with the project yesterday saved my life.
> (noun clause)

Is "Julia helped me with the project yesterday" the subject?

Comment: Alternative "noun" usage (spread across two sentences, so "that" in the second references the entirety of the first sentence) - *Julia helped me with the project yesterday. **That** saved my life*. Where in the *spoken* version, ***that*** and ***which*** can be completely interchangeable without affecting the meaning - but in the *written* version people will start arguing over the "correct" determiner and punctuation.

Comment: ...also there's the "gerund noun" version *Julia['s] **helping** me with the project yesterday saved my life* (the highlighted gerund is obviously a noun, since it's functioning as the subject of the verb ***saved***).

Comment: Why do you think there's only one "correct" way? There's several ways, and these are two of them.